# Error while installing heroku using gem on Windows

Tags: heroku, rubygems, git-bash

While installing `heroku` I will get the below mentioned error:

```
$ gem install heroku

Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing heroku:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/heroku-3.99.4
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20181030-11376-16mqlg7.rb extconf.rb
extconf.rb:1:in `<main>':  heroku must be installed from cli.heroku.com. This gem is no longer available. (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/heroku-3.99.4 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.3.0/heroku-3.99.4/gem_make.out
```

What's the problem, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku's [Ruby CLI](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli/) is no longer maintained and shouldn't be used:

> heroku must be installed from cli.heroku.com. This gem is no longer available.

Any resources telling you to install the Ruby CLI are outdated.

The [new CLI](https://github.com/heroku/cli/) is built in JavaScript. Heroku [provides installers for macOS and Windows, and a snap for Ubuntu](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#download-and-install). It is also possible to install the CLI [via `npm`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#npm), but this isn't recommended in most instances.

Comment: That seems more accurate than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying gem install, check out an [alternative installation method for heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057819/error-while-installing-heroku-using-gem-in-windows), like downloading [`heroku-win32-x64.tar.gz`](https://cli-assets.heroku.com/heroku-win32-x64.tar.gz) and uncompress it in a folder of your choice.

Then make sure to add it to your `%PATH%`.
Or `$PATH` if you are in a `git bash` session:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/c/path/to/heroku
```